# How to use GPS only in WinJS Geolocator?

Tags: windows, gps, geolocation, winjs

I recently started writing an app in WinJS, which runs on Windows Phone and Win8.
Even if I called

```
geolocator.desiredAccuracy = Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionAccuracy.high;
```

the coordinate object returned is still sometimes (in fact, often) inaccurate -- namely, calculated from Wifi Triangulation, IP Address etc, not from GPS. One significant sign is that the `speedd`, which I needed most, is absent.
Meanwhile, the GetPosition method returns immediately, as the low accuracy data is available.

Is there any way to force the system to use only GPS signals, such that it'll stall and wait for GPS when we call an async GetPosition method, rather than returning the low accuracy result?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to force the system to use GPS-only signals in the manner you describe. What kind of accuracy are you receiving, and what kind of accuracy are you looking for?

You are correct in setting the `desiredAccuracy` property to `High`. Perhaps it is worth setting the `desiredAccuracyInMeters` property instead, as it provides more granularity and control of the accuracy of the position results.

One way to check the source of the coordinates is by using the `PositionSource` enumeration. If the value is set to `1`, the position was obtained from satellite data.

A small note regarding the `speed`: [it is optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.speed.aspx) for the location provider to return this value. The Windows Location provider does not set this property, and will consequently return a value of `NULL`.

For more information, [check out the Geolocation sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66) on MSDN.

Hope this helps!